# ¿Cómo puedo navegar entre más de 2 activities en Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, activity

He estado buscando cómo y no he encontrado nada y es algo frustrante. Intenté con algo que era viewbinding pero no funcionó, y lo primero que intenté fue este pedazo de código en el Mainactivity pero solo me funcionó para navegar entre 2 pantallas:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnclicInicio()
        
    }



fun btnclicInicio(){
    val btnIrAInicio = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnIrAInicio)
        btnIrAInicio.setOnClickListener{
            val ventanaIncio: Intent = Intent(applicationContext, Inicio::class.java)
            startActivity(ventanaIncio)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: perdón, había añadido una respuesta, pero era en lenguaje java, luego leí que tu pregunta era para kotlin

Comment: Ntp, sabes como hacerlo en Kotlin de casualidad?

Comment: La verdad qie no he trabajo con kotlin, y aventurarme en darte respuesta sería después de investigar, y seguro que si esperas un poco, algún miembro de la comunidad te responderá sin problema

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, y te lo agradezco, si esperaré pero seguiré estudiando

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, que quieres hacer exactamente? La respuesta de @el.trasgu es lo que necesitabas?

Comment: Mmm quería navegar entre varias pantallas, tengo muchas activities, y realmente no sé si este bien como lo estoy haciendo ó si este bien lo que dijo @el.trisgu , ese código lo tengo en mi Main, pero si intento hacer algo similar en el resto de las activities se me crashea la app cuando hago clic en el botón de siguiente mientras es emulada. Tu sabes qué es lo correcto?

Comment: Tanto el código que muestras como el de la respuesta que te dieron son correctos. No deberías tener problemas haciendo lo mismo con las demás activities. La causa del error que mencionas debe ser otra pero no podemos ayudarte sin ver el mensaje de error. Aunque si quieres mejorar la navegación deberías probar el [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

Comment: Podrías orientarme a como poder usar el navigation component? Me serviría mucho, si no puedes, intentaré a como estaba haciendo pero te lo agradezco

Comment: Hay un montón de información oficial sobre como usarlo. En el enlace que te dejé tienes mas de 20 links explicando en detalle como aplicarlo a distintas situaciones. Si estás buscando un paso a paso, creo que tu mejor opción es hacer el [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation)

Comment: Lo leeré y practicaré con atención, te agradezco el tiempo! Btw, les puedo dar algún like o punto por su ayuda? También soy nuevo en el sitio

Comment: El funcionamiento del sitio se explica en el [tour]. Necesitas una reputación mayor a 15 para poder votar las respuestas.

Comment: @AxelGrimaldo ya tienes la reputación suficiente para dar votos positivos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver, tu código no estaría mal orientado

para pasar de un activity a otro, se usaría;

```
//this, sería el concepto actual, o sea, la acticity en la que estas
//nuevaActivity sería la activity a la que deseas ir
val pantalla1 = Intent(this, nuevaActivity::class.java)
       //Si por ejemplo deseas enviar algún dato utilizas los putExtra, 
       //en éste caso, cogemos el texto de los textBox etUser y etPass 
       //y los enviamos al acticity que accedemos identificados por una clave
       //"usuario" y "contrasena"
       pantalla1.putExtra("usuario", etUser.text.toString())
       pantalla1.putExtra("contrasena", etPass.text.toString())
       startActivity(pantalla1)

    //para recuperar la información enviada desde la acticity anterior:
    //instanciamos un nuevo bundle y metemos en el los datos enviados en el intent
    val bundle = intent.extras
    //metemos en variables los valores por su clave "usuario" y "contrasena"
    val user = bundle.get("usuario")
    val pass = bundle.get("contrasena")
    //mostramos los valores de las variables en textBox
    tvUsuario.text = getString(R.string.welcome, user)
    tvContrasena.text = getString(R.string.welcome, pass)
```

Para cerrar la nueva activity y volver a la anterior, poner en el botón simplemente:

```
    finish();
```